# Getstream.io Flatfeed showing unknown user for all activities

Tags: react-native, getstream-io

I´m trying to implement flatfeed on my react native app but having a hard time trying to get the proper actor info on stream (I´m suspicious that is where the problem resides), this is what I have:

```
const stream = require('getstream');
  const client = stream.connect('xxxx', null, 'x');
  ...
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}} forceInset={{ top: 'always' }}>
       <Button onPress={handlePress} title="test"> </Button>
      <StreamApp
            apiKey="xxx"
            appId="x"
            token={userProfile.ActivityFeedToken}
        >
          <FlatFeed
            notify = "true"
            />
        </StreamApp>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
```

Token is retrieved from local storage on the device, using AsyncStorage and the put on userProfile. ActivityFeedToken using useState(). I have validated the content after retrieval and it actually holds the token, so this piece looks good.

Next I included a test button to add an activity just for testing purposes, and this is where the problem starts

```
handlePress = async () =>
  {
      // For the feed group 'user' and user id 'eric' get the feed
      // The user token is generated server-side for this user
      const ericFeed = client.feed('timeline', 'user1',userProfile.ActivityFeedToken);
      const activity = { actor: client.user('user1').ref(), verb: 'add',
      object: 'picture:20',
      foreign_id: 'picture:20',
      message: 'Beautiful bird!' };

      // Add the activity to the feed
      let result = await ericFeed.addActivity(activity);
  };
```

This kind of works, but gets me this result:

[image: Unknown user]

And if for the new activity I try with de userId instead of the user reference:

```
const activity = { actor: 'user1', verb: 'add',
      object: 'picture:20',
      foreign_id: 'picture:20',
      message: 'Beautiful bird!' };
```

This is what I get, regardless of being the same user:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
[Error: {"detail":"The policy \"Don't impersonate other users\" (900) blocked this request, please consult the documentation https://getstream.io/docs/","status_code":403,"code":17,"exception":"NotAllowedException","duration":"0.20ms"} with HTTP status code 403]
```

What am I doing wrong? please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

From your second call (an id inlined with 403 error), we know your token is correct for `user1` so problem is enrichment because you're putting a reference but you can't resolve it.

- `client.feed('timeline', 'user1', userProfile.ActivityFeedToken)`
- `actor: client.user('user1').ref()`

These two pieces together is the problem. It means you didn't create a user with id `user1` before but you added an activity created by that user. While retrieving user because activity referencing it should be returned, it isn't expanded.

Comment: Thanks, but I´m not sure I´m following... what your are saying is for client feed Im using 'user1' and for the new activity I´m using the reference to that user, that is why it´s not working, right?

But in that case my second option should work since Im using 'user1' in both client and new activity, but what I´m getting is the impersonate error

Comment: have you created the user with id `user1`? It seems you were able to create the activity w/o issues but reading failed so reference to that user isn't resolved.

Comment: If you can give your app id, I can validate better.

Comment: If I use data explorer I can see the user is created, (well I assume it´s created since I can see this "user" and "timeline" feeds. I´m testing now with a different user: "8112121212" which successfully created token and can see his info on data explorer... however if I use the user reference for the new activity what I see under actor column on data explorer is "{"created_at":"2020-06-18T18:31:51.331232Z","updated_at":"2020-06-18T18:31:51.331232Z","id":"8112121212","data":{"name":"Unknown"}}" and if I only use the user ID (8112121212) I get the impersonate error.... App id is 82684